# Data extracted from a csv file from server is missing new line character

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv, filereader

I am loading a csv file from server on client through an ajax call and parsing it to get a list of lines. However, my code cannot find newline character and it treats entire file as 1 line.

Here is my code

```
$.ajax({ url: "./data.csv", success: function(data) {
            var lines = data.split("\n");
           // I also tried this but did not work
           // var lines = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
            console.log(lines.length); // output is 1
        }
    });
```

Here is my CSV (NOTE: the delimiter is **;** instead of **,** but that shouldn't cause this issue)

```
category;title;description;price;additional
Breakfast;Traditional Breakfast;flour tortilla, scrambled eggs, jack cheese, mild sauce;3.95
Breakfast;Traditional Breakfast;flour tortilla, scrambled eggs, sausage jack cheese, mild sauce;5.95
```

Any ideas?

Comment: make sure that when the message is sent from the server it sent with the new lines characters. otherwise you would have to write something a lot more complex, like finding the index of the last char of each line and splitting it there. for that i would parse the response with a loop since regex is problematic here, but i'm sure there are several ways it could be done

Comment: @user2033402 and how do i make sure that the new line characters are not skipped?

Comment: that depends on your server. i dont know what server software you are using, but this sort of things are usually configurable. the message suppose to contain #CF ant the end of each line. you can use Telerik Fiddler to check exactly what the message you are sending or receiving contains, but in order to change that you have to have access to the server

Answer (score 1):

Have you check the format of your CSV file? It maybe use LF instead of CF for newline. Try this:

```
$.ajax({url: "./data.csv", success: function(data) {
  var lines = data.replace("\r\n", "\n").replace("\r", "\n").split("\n");
  // the rest of your code
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this did not fix the entire issue.
Now, the length is 2 instead of 3 where 1st in array is category;title;description;price;additional and 2nd line in array is the rest of the content in my csv

Comment: What's your server's response? Does it strip the newline characters?

Comment: Yes, it does. It is a single line string

Comment: What is your server? Have you check your server configuration? It looks like you have output filtering or compression. Or, can you try to use another file extension e.g. data.txt?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which language you are using for server side coding.I have just scrambled some code in ASP.NET mvc and Ajax to find a solution for your question.You can change code the as per requirement.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/



    public JsonResult _ReadCSVFiles()
    {
        string[] values = LoadCsv(@"F:\a.csv");
        return Json(values, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    private string[] LoadCsv(string filename)
    {
        string fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);


        fileContent = fileContenet.Replace('\n', '\r');
        string[] lines = fileContent.Split(new char[] { '\r' },
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);



        return lines;
    }
}
```

In the ajax

```
  $.ajax({
         url: "/Home/_ReadCSVFiles",

         success: function (doc) {
             alert(doc.length)

        }
     });
```

Comment: There is no server side logic at all. It is a static website made in html css and javascript

Comment: This link may be helpful stackoverflow.com/a/12289296/901048